Positive definite Hessian implies convex function.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f: A \to R$ be continuously twice differentiable. Suppose $\nabla^2 f(c) > 0$ for some $c \in A$. Prove that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $c$ such that $$\frac12(f(x) + f(y)) \geq f(\frac{x + y}{2})$$ for all $x, y \in U$.

I tried defining $g(x, y) := \frac12(f(x) - f(y)) - f(\frac{x + y}{2})$. Taking partial derivatives gives me
$$\frac{\partial^2 g(x, y)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(c, c) = \frac14 \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(c)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 g(x, y)}{\partial y_i \partial y_j}(c, c) = \frac14 \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(c)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 g(x, y)}{\partial x_i \partial y_j}(c, c) = -\frac14 \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(c)$$
Therefore,
$$\nabla^2 g(c, c) = \frac14 \begin{bmatrix}
\nabla^2 f(c) & -\nabla^2 f(c) \\
-\nabla^2 f(c) & \nabla^2 f(c)
\end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}
\nabla^2 f(c) & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
From which I conclude that $\nabla^2 g$ is positive semi-definite at $(c, c)$, but I want it to be positive definite. I also easily get that $\nabla g(c, c) = 0$, so positive definiteness would imply what I want. I'm not sure what went wrong (are my calculations correct?). I also wonder if there is a way to apply the total derivative operator directly here, i.e. to avoid all the partial derivatives.

I think you can use 2nd-order definition of convexity (Hessian is PSD) to get the zeroth order definition of convexity (chord is above the graph) for which mid-convexity is just a special case.

The problem gives to me that the Hessian of $f$ is positive definite, so it seems weird to throw that out for a weaker condition. Anyway, do you have an idea of how you could go about proving this?

I don't see an issue. Actually, you can prove for strict inequality if Hessian is PD.

Okay, so my expression for $\nabla^2 g(c, c)$ should give that $g$ has a minimum at $(c, c)$. I guess this is possible because all of the eigenvalues are positive or $0$, but I still don't see why this is true.

You can try applying taylor series
